# jQuery AJAX post fails in IE, works in other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery/AJAX for my login form. The following script works in the latest versions of Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome, but fails on bot IE6 and IE9. Regardless of whether I type the correct or a wrong password, my error function is invoked with "readystate=0, status=0, statusText="Error: Invalid argument.".

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
      var thistarget = this.target;
      jQuery.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          if (typeof xhr.responseText !== "undefined") {
            $('strong.message').text(xhr.responseText);
          } else {
            $('strong.message').text("Bad username and/or password");
          }
          $('div.alert').show();
        },
        success: function(response) {
          document.location.href='/';
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Now that you've identified the problem, you can safely start debugging.

Comment: Have you alerted the response in success callback?

Comment: Thanks Pierre, that solved it ;) I've been googling/coding for a while  trying to fix this, but of course I figured it out after posting the Q. If I remove the url-parameter, it works in IE as well. Should I update my question with that info, or answer my own Q?

Comment: Wow @Pierre that is most simple and sure shot ever.